# Regrouping a list

Tags: c#, list

If I have a list like this.

[0 , 1, 2]

[2 , 3, 4]

[4 , 5, 6]

[7 , 8, 9]

[9 , 10, 11]

[11 , 12, 13]

> How do I separate them into two lists like this:

**List 1:**

[0 , 1, 2]

[2 , 3, 4]

[4 , 5, 6]

**List 2:**

[7 , 8, 9]

[9 , 10, 11]

[11 , 12, 13]

The Condition is that if the next value in the list does not contain a value within the previous one, it will create another list.

Comment: To clarify, you have a List of Lists, and you want to separate it into two Lists of Lists?

Comment: Oh. I have List and then store each created list after separating into a list of lists. @MarioIshac

Comment: [List<T>.CopyTo(startIndex, destination, fromIndex, elementsCount)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.copyto). Add `.ToList()`, eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rely on LINQ:

```cs
var data = new List<int[]>
{
    new int[] {0 , 1, 2},
    new int[] {2 , 3, 4},
    new int[] {4 , 5, 6},
    new int[] {7 , 8, 9},
    new int[] {9 , 10, 11},
    new int[] {11 , 12, 13}
};

var result = data
    .Aggregate(
        new List<List<int[]>>(), 
        (accumulator, item) => {
            var canMerge = accumulator.LastOrDefault()?.Last().Any(v => item.Contains(v)) ?? false;

            if (canMerge) {
                accumulator.Last().Add(item);
                return accumulator;
            }

            accumulator.Add(new List<int[]>{ item });
            return accumulator;
        });
```

Comment: There is an error after LastOrDefault()?. It says invalid "."

Comment: [Null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) is available starting from c#6 - please make sure that you use this version or higher. See online code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YkNHnM

Answer (score 1):

this will be work if you just check one and next only

```
List<int[]> Targ = new List<int[]>()
{
    new int[] {0,1,2},
    new int[] {2,3,4},
    new int[] {4,5,6},
    new int[] {7,8,9},
    new int[] {9,10,11},
    new int[] {11,12,13},
};

List<List<int[]>> ArrLists = new List<List<int[]>>();

List<int[]> Element = new List<int[]>();

for ( int i = 0; i < Targ.Count - 1; i++ )
{
    bool Added = false;
    for ( int j = 0; j < Targ[i].Length; j++)
    {
        // checking
        if ( Targ[i+1].Contains(Targ[i][j]) )
        {
            Element.Add(Targ[i]);
            Added = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // if array(int) is not added, it means there's a difference between elements.
    if ( !Added )
    {
        ArrLists.Add(Element);

        Element = new List<int[]>();
        Element.Add(Targ[i]);
    }
}

// Add Last Element to list
ArrLists.Add(Element);
```